# How to safely code directory delete based on parameter?

Tags: design-patterns, cmd, scripting, delete-file

I have a script which orchestrates a number of processes, all of which create logs in a location which is defined in a parameter file (ie separate to the script). Prior to running the processes, the script empties the log location e.g.

```
rem LOGLOC is loaded from a parameter file
Del /F /Q /S %LOGLOC%\*.*
```

Clearly very dangerous. If for any reason LOGLOC was incorrectly defined, this could be catastrophic. I modified the script to add some safety...

```
if "%LOGLOC%" equ "" (
    ECHO FATAL ERROR: LOGLOC not defined
    exit /b 1
)
Del /F /Q /S %LOGLOC%\*.*
```

... but does not account for instances where LOGLOC might be accidentally defined as `'.'` or `'..'`.

Is there a better pattern for checking a parameter before using it in a potentially harmful way?

EDIT: I'm adding the following validation rules as suggested by Fejese.

1. Check it's at least 4 chars in length e.g. C:\L
2. Validate that char 1 in A-Z
3. Validate that chars 2,3 = :\
4. Validate that the path exists and is a directory

If I can figure these out I will post the results but credit will go to Fejese for pointing me in the right direction...

Comment: Is it an option to get confirmation from user? Ie. making it interactive? Or does this script have to run without human intervention?

Comment: The script runs unattended every night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no way for the script to tell whether the parameter got is safe or not, unless you set up some rules.

- You could hard code a prefix in the script which has to be matched.
- You could restrict the delete pattern to only remove log files for example.